# Did any switch have many queuing in each port or it have only sharing one queue?

Tags: switch

Did any switch have many queue in each port or it have only one sharing queue?
I want to know the packet how to queue in one switch. 
In switch is each port have special queue for packet receive and send?
Or the switch only have one sharing queue to the packet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is depending on some vendors with different technologies. 
basically, switch have different queue for each port. there are two technologies, (cut-trough and store-and-forward) 
cut-trough : buffering 1st 64 bit and passing rest of frame to destination port if no error occurs in first 64 bit

store-and-forward : buffering whole frame and if no error found in frame, frame will send to destination port.

Comment: So each port have special queue for the packet send and receive?
For example if one port have congestion the other port may not be influences.

Comment: Yes you are right. but this thin can be different on different vendor models. but generally its true.

Comment: If the two input port have the same output port how the two queue to departure their packet?

Comment: It will duplicate same packet to two ques respectively for each destination ports.